# Recommendations for email server with REST API?

Tags: email, rest, listserv

We are evaluating email servers and would appreciate recommendations.  Our basic requirements are:

- REST API - with option to also receive parsed messages as well as
  sending
- Spam and virus filtering
- Access to log files - to view bounce messages
- Deliverability - features to help avoid blacklisting and identify if
  emails are being blacklisted

The use cases we envisage are broadly:

- Transactional emails
- Multiple independently managed email newsletters
- Multiple independently managed listservs

Our preference would be for an open source application that we can host ourselves.  However, we are open to web apps as well.  Some of the options we are looking at are:

- Lyris ListManager - currently using this, but license is very expensive
- Mailman
- Sympa
- Postmark - http://www.postmarkapp.com
- Mailgun - http://www.mailgun.net

Are there others you know of that we should consider?  If you have experience with using any of the above then that would also be great to hear about.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you reviewed the [Zimbra Collaboration Server](http://www.excitingip.net/544/open-source-email-server-application-zimbra-collaboration-server-zcs/)?  I've never used it, I just found it with a quick google search.

This [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent) about MTAs that might help.

Answer (score 0):

We use Sympa here.  Although it is possible to make it do anti-spam and anti-virus, we actually have that function in our central mail gateway and so only use Sympa to check headers with status inserted by the gateway.

I've found Sympa to be extremely flexible and extendible - the template and plugin architecture is very good.  However the documentation on the more obscure features and how to create customisations leave a lot to be desired :(.

The ability to have multiple virtual listservers, external datasources for owners, moderators or members, and auto-creation of mailing lists from XML or on the fly is really helpful.  It's also good at handling the large scale (20,000+ lists) that we have (you need 6.1.11 or later, though).

I would definitely not consider Mailman - its a good lightweight server, but can't handle the large scale or multiple virtual listservers, and the web interface is nowhere near as good. It also doesnt have the extendability that Sympa has.  We migrated several Mailman and Majordomo servers into a single multi-domain Sympa installation without difficulty.